# Calling a program using the MSDOS EXEC API (int21h with AX=4Bh)

Tags: exec, dosbox, quickbasic

I am trying to use the DOS API "EXEC" (int 21h with AH=4Bh) to load a program. I tried several things, but it doesn't work. I am getting the result code AX=2 which means "File not found". I think there is something not correct with the param block, but I am not sure what. Do you have any suggestions how to make the code work?

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
CLS

DIM Array(0 TO 127)  AS INTEGER
DEF SEG = VARSEG(Array(0))

TYPE paramblk
        segenv AS INTEGER
        cmdline AS INTEGER
        cseg AS INTEGER
        fcb1 AS INTEGER
        f1seg AS INTEGER
        fcb2 AS INTEGER
        f2seg AS INTEGER
END TYPE

TYPE RegTypeX
        ax AS INTEGER
        bx AS INTEGER
        cx AS INTEGER
        dx AS INTEGER
        bp AS INTEGER
        si AS INTEGER
        di AS INTEGER
        flags AS INTEGER
        ds AS INTEGER
        es AS INTEGER
END TYPE

DIM regs AS RegTypeX
DIM p AS paramblk

cmdline$ = CHR$(0) + "" + CHR$(&HD)
emptyfcb$ = CHR$(0) + "???????????" + CHR$(0) + CHR$(0) + CHR$(0) + CHR$(0) + CHR$(0) + CHR$(0) + CHR$(0) + CHR$(0) + CHR$(0) + CHR$(0) + CHR$(0) + CHR$(0) + CHR$(0) + CHR$(0) + CHR$(0) + CHR$(0) + CHR$(0) + CHR$(0) + CHR$(0) + CHR$(0) + CHR$(0) +  _
CHR$(0) + CHR$(0) + CHR$(0) + CHR$(0)

p.segenv = 0 ' 0 = copy environment of parent
p.cmdline = SADD(cmdline$)
p.cseg = SSEG(cmdline$)
p.fcb1 = SADD(emptyfcb$)
p.f1seg = SSEG(emptyfcb$)
p.fcb2 = SADD(emptyfcb$)
p.f2seg = SSEG(emptyfcb$)

REM I tried both of these
CHNAME$ = "AYDOS1.EXE" + CHR$(0)
REM chname$ = "C:\QB71\AYDOS1.EXE" + CHR$(0)

regs.ax = &H4B00
regs.ds = SSEG(CHNAME$)
regs.dx = SADD(CHNAME$)
regs.es = VARSEG(p)
regs.bx = VARPTR(p)
CALL interrupt(&H21, regs, regs)

PRINT "AX = ", regs.ax  ' I am receiving AX=2 (File not found) as result
```

Note: I am not using the `SHELL` command, because using the EXEC API, I want to call non-EXE files in the further steps

Note 2: The environment is DOSBox and I am using QuickBasic 7.1 (with option /L)

Comment: Hmm, from my admittedly vague memory, that seems okay. I *assume* you've actually confirmed the `exe` file exists, yes? You're also not checking the carry flag for error but I assume that's okay here since a *working* load-and-exec would be obvious due to the fact it would run your program :-)

Comment: Yes, I am very sure that the EXE file exists. I have found something out: 
When I write `call interruptx` instead of `call interrupt`, the file will be found, and now I get error 8 instead (insufficient memory) if the file exists, otherwise 2 (file not found).
I have read that it is a known problem ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/10067627/488539 ), which I tried to solve via `int21h/ah=4a`, but it didn't work neither inside the QuickBASIC debugger, nor "outside" (i.e. as compiled EXE).

Comment: I am afraid it is not possible for a QuickBASIC program to limit its own memory to give another process control.
Eventually, I had given up, and implemented it with assembler, which now works perfectly. Still, it would be good to know if it would have been possible in BASIC at all.

Comment: @DanielMarschall Older versions of Microsoft BASIC, [such as GW-BASIC](http://www.antonis.de/qbebooks/gwbasman/clear.html), allow one to use `CLEAR , maxMem, stack` to limit the amount of memory available to the BASIC interpreter/program to `maxMem`, which includes the BASIC `stack` size in the calculation (i.e. `maxMem >= stack`). QuickBASIC, however, only allows you to specify the stack size, managing dynamic memory itself. The statement will also close files, nullify string data and more, acting as a sort of "reset" for program state. Whether that might suit your needs is unknown to me.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that the version of QuickBASIC that came with PDS 7.1 (i.e. "QBX", or "QuickBASIC eXtended") did have a switch `/Nof[rills]` that disabled some features to save memory, though I'm still uncertain if it would work for you. It's documented as using _"about 19K less memory, freeing this memory for other uses during program development. These features are unavailable when `/Nof` is in use: Utility menu and commands, Options menu and commands, and Help menu and commands."_